# how can i change the navigation bar of MFMailComposeViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to change the navigation bar of MFMailComposeViewController to black color.

how can i change.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that `MFMailComposeViewController` inherits from `UINavigationController` so it also has `navigationBar` property.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

Comment: you were a little faster than me ^^.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is quite dated but for someone who might find it useful, try:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailController  = [MFMailComposeViewController new];

[mailController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithHue:240.0f/359.0f
                                                      saturation:85.0f/100.0f 
                                                      brightness:60.0f/100.0f 
                                                           alpha:0.0f]];
```